# How do I ask windbg for the fullpath of the dump file it has open

Tags: windbg

When you open a dump with windbg it outputs something like:

> Loading Dump File [\serverX\dumpfiles\myapp.dmp] 
>   User Mini Dump File with Full Memory: Only application data is available
>   ...

How do I ask windbg for that info at any time in the future?
For example I ran

```
.cls
.wtitle foo
```

now that full path is gone.

Is there other file specific info I can get (Not crash related)
date time stamp for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple way to get the info back except opening the dump again (try `.restart`). But there are commands to mimic similar behavior. I'll go through those line by line.

> Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.15003.1001 X86 
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

That information is part of the `version` command.

> Loading Dump File [D:...\demo.dmp]

This is also shown in `version` and you can use `||` if you want less output.

> User Mini Dump File with Full Memory: Only application data is available

This information is not directly accessible. The `||` command tells you that it's a user mode dump. To get the exact flags which were used to create the dump, use

```
.shell -ci ".dumpdebug" findstr "MiniDump"
```

> ************* Symbol Path validation summary ************** 
>   Response                         Time (ms)     Location
>   Deferred                                       SRV*f:\debug
> \symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
>   Symbol search path is: SRV*f:\debug\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

You can see the symbol path info with `.sympath`.

> Executable search path is:

Use `.exepath` for this.

> Windows 7 Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) MP (2 procs) Free x86 compatible
>   Product: WinNt, suite: SingleUserTS Personal
>   6.1.7601.18015 (win7sp1_gdr.121129-1432)
>   Machine Name:
>   Debug session time: Tue Jun 10 17:41:42.000 2014 (UTC + 1:00)
>   System Uptime: 0 days 0:27:20.402
>   Process Uptime: 0 days 0:00:27.000

You can get that by `vertarget`.

> This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it. 
>   The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
>   (e40.a44): Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not available)

I always use `.exr -1`, but the output is not close to that.

> eax=00000000 ebx=0039f4a4 ecx=00000000 edx=00193d1c esi=022924f8 edi=0039f3ec 
>   eip=0024008d esp=0039f3d8 ebp=0039f3f8 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
>   cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010202
>   0024008d 8b01            mov     eax,dword ptr [ecx]  ds:002b:00000000=????????

These are the registers, accessible with `r`, usually of thread 0, so `~0s;r` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

use !dumptype

```
C:\>kd -c "!dumptype;q" -z e:\testdumps\MEMORY.DMP  | grep -A 5 initial
kd> kd: Reading initial command '!dumptype;q'
e:\testdumps\MEMORY.DMP
Mini
TYPE: 6130d710
quit:

C:\>
```